# How to let a self referential binding?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a `let` and I need one of the bindings to refer to itself in the body. i.e. I need something like this:

```
(let ((my-value (make-value :some-data 2784 :next-value my-value)))
  ; ...)
```

This fails because `my-value` at the definition is unbound. I think I might be able to use `setf` to assign the value but it's not a good general solution for me (e.g. because of side-effects).

How can I handle this situation? maybe there's a way to have a forward declaration?

Comment: You'll need some form of base-case as the evaluation (if this were possible) is still eager.

Comment: @user2864740 i.e. I must use `setf`?

Comment: referring to an object, which does not exist, makes no sense. Create the object, first.

Comment: Don't forget to set `*print-circle*` to `T`; just saying...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think I might be able to use setf to assign the value but it's not a good general solution for me (e.g. because of side-effects).

Some languages are designed to support self-referential variables, like algebra systems where you can write `x = x * 4 - 2` and the system solve your equation for `x`.
In Common Lisp the evaluation rules say that you must be able to evaluate `x` in the arguments of `make-value` before being able to assign a meaningful value to `x`.

You could delay operations with a `lambda`. For example, you could add a `lazy-let` macro which would transform this:

```
(lazy-let ((x (make-value :some-data d :next-value x)))
  ...)
```

... into that:

```
(let* ((x0 nil)
       (x (make-value :some-data d :next-value (lambda () x0))))
  (setf x0 x)
  ...)
```

But then you would need to *force* the lazy value to be computed, with a `funcall`. Lazy languages like Haskell hide this behavior for you.

If you were writing in Prolog, you would say:

```
make_value(X,D) :- X = value{data: D, next: X}.
```

This works thanks to unification, which among other things can be used to perform an interesting kind of side-effects, namely *setting a variable at most once*.
This, however, is not possible directly in Common Lisp (you can implement unification in Lisp, but you should probably not if the sole purpose is to avoid `setf`).

What happens in the above examples is that side-effects are hidden. 
My point is that there is nothing magic: somehow, there must be a side-effect to establish a link between an object and itself, even if it is not visible.

You can do the same and provide a side-effect free function over an implementation which locally perform side-effects. That's perfectly acceptable. 
First, define your type:

```
(defstruct (value (:constructor make-value%))
  some-data
  next-value)
```

The basic constructor is named `make-value%`, a name which should probably not be exported by your package. Then, you define the user-facing constructor:

```
(defun make-value (&key some-data (next nil nextp))
  (let ((value (make-value% :some-data some-data)))
    (setf (value-next-value value) (if nextp next value))
    value))
```

The implementation carefully wraps a local side-effect into a function which, from an external point of view, does not mutate its environment (remark: allocating memory is a side effect too). It allows the user to provide a next element, but by default it links the structure to itself.
  Here is an example usage:

```
(let ((x (make-value :some-data 1234)))
  (assert (eq x (value-next-value x))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You should follow the advice from the commenters and create the object and then modify it:

```
(setq *print-circle* t)
(let ((x (list 1 2 3)))
  (setf (second x) x)
  x)
==> #1=(1 #1# 3)
```

If you really want to go crazy, you can use the reader magic:

```
(let ((x '#1=(1 #1# 3)))
  x)
==> #1=(1 #1# 3)
```

However, this creates a *quoted* object, which you should *not* modify later.

It will also create a unique object, i.e., if not a fresh object, i.e., each invocation of the above code will return the same object:

```
(defun unsafe ()
  '#1=(1 #1# 3))
(eq (unsafe) (unsafe))
==> T
```